# C++ Why methods of objects are accessed by . through a reference but by -> through a pointer

Tags: c++

This is a question for curiosity, which I have not found the good answer yet.
Suppose in "main.cc" I have the following code

```
namespace {

class MyClass {

public:
int GetNumber() const {return number_;}

MyClass(const int number) :
number_(number) {
}

private:
const int number_;

};

const MyClass* GetPointerToClass(const MyClass &c) {
    return (&c);
}

}  // namespace

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    const MyClass my_constant_class(5);

    const MyClass* const pointer1_to_constant_class = GetPointerToClass(
        my_constant_class);
    printf("%d\n", pointer1_to_constant_class->GetNumber());

    const MyClass* const pointer2_to_constant_class = &my_constant_class;
    printf("%d\n", pointer2_to_constant_class->GetNumber());

    const MyClass& reference_to_constant_class = my_constant_class;
    printf("%d\n", reference_to_constant_class.GetNumber());

    const MyClass copy_of_my_class = my_constant_class;
    printf("%d\n", copy_of_my_class.GetNumber());

    return 0;
}
```

Now when I run the program, it prints:
5
5
5
5

The thing I'm curious about is why the program compiles and runs successfully?

In particular (according to my understanding, correct if I am wrong):

value of pointer1_to_constant_class is assigned to a reference of a const reference.

value of pointer2_to_constant_class is assigned to a reference of an object.

(so although both pointers are of the same type, they are assigned to different types)

value of reference_to_constant_class is assigned to an object.

value of copy_to_my_class is assigned to an object.

(so reference and object are assigned to the same type)

So why we have to call pointer2_to_constant_class->GetNumber, 
if it is assigned to a reference of an object.

Also, why there is no difference in calling reference_to_constant_class.GetNumber(),
versus copy_of_my_class.GetNumber(),

if one is an object, another just a reference?

Comment: I concur with Lightness' answer. https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp4_PointerReference.html is a good reading on the confusing issue of &.

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is all wrong. I can't do much more than address your specific observations. I *think* you're getting confused by the address-of operator `&`, which has effectively no relationship with the symbol `&` as found in reference types (or with bitwise-`AND`).

- `T&`: the type "reference to `T`";
- `&a`: an expression evaluating to the *address of* the object `a` (a pointer!);
- `a & b`: an expression evaluating to the result of `AND`ing the numbers `a` and `b`.

These three usages of `&` are (confusingly) unrelated. So, neither `return (&c)` nor `&my_constant_class` have anything to do with references.

Reference and pointer semantics are actually remarkably simple, but once you've gone off-piste with misconceptions there's no coming back. That is one reason it is really important to learn C++ from a good, peer-reviewed book, rather than from random tutorials on the internet, your mate down the pub, or not at all!

---

> value of pointer1_to_constant_class is assigned to a reference of a const reference.

No. A pointer of type `MyClass*` is assigned to `pointer1_to_constant_class`. No references here.

> value of pointer2_to_constant_class is assigned to a reference of an object.

No. A pointer of type `MyClass*` is assigned to `pointer2_to_constant_class`. No references here.

> (so although both pointers are of the same type, they are assigned to different types)

They are both of the same type, but have been assigned to different values.

> value of reference_to_constant_class is assigned to an object.

An object is assigned to the object referred to by `reference_to_constant_class`, yes.

> value of copy_to_my_class is assigned to an object.

A new object `copy_to_my_class` is declared and copy-initialised from an object, yes.

> (so reference and object are assigned to the same type)

You never assign a reference.

> So why we have to call pointer2_to_constant_class->GetNumber, if it is assigned to a reference of an object.

It's not. `pointer2_to_constant_class` is a pointer.

> Also, why there is no difference in calling reference_to_constant_class.GetNumber(), versus copy_of_my_class.GetNumber(),
>
> if one is an object, another just a reference?

**We access member functions like `a.b()` whether `a` is the object itself, or a reference to it.**

**We access member functions like `a->b()` when `a` is a pointer to an object.**

Comment: I am still confused on:

    const MyClass& reference_to_constant_class = my_constant_class;

    const MyClass copy_of_my_class = my_constant_class;

On the right sides, we have the same types, but not on the left. Why that works?

Comment: @MariusLatinis: Because references are magical aliases that do their best, in terms of syntax, to work _transparently_. Put another way, "it just does" because the language was designed that way. Speaking more generally, there are _loads_ of examples of initialisations where the RHS and LHS have different types, so this situation isn't as surprising as you think.